# Escape ampersand in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

```
ANSIBLE_WORK_DIR=${ANSIBLE_WORK_DIR:-$(pwd)/ansible}

ansible_work_dir() {
  echo "${ANSIBLE_WORK_DIR}"
}

ansible_run() {
  local cmd
  ansible_dir=$(ansible_work_dir)

  cmd="cd $ansible_dir && ansible-playbook --extra-vars env=${ENV}"
  $cmd "${@}"
}

ansible_run playbooks/secrets/write.yml
```

My problem is that what I got is as result is:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/ansible '&&' ansible-playbook --extra-vars env=test playbooks/secrets/write.yml
```

I mean for some strange reason the double ampersand is escaped. How could I solve the issue?

Comment: Take a look at [Bash FAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: @randomir, ...that would do what the OP wants in a very narrow sense, but it also risks doing a bunch of things the OP *doesn't* want -- particularly given the use of `"$@"` passed as a separate argument, which `eval` will effectively split akin to `$*` and then re-parse (from the beginning, thus treating `$()` inside a literal string as an instruction to run a command substitution). Given the correctness and security risks, it's a difficult thing to recommend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&&` isn't really being escaped; it's just that it has no special meaning inside a simple command.

When you write something like this:

```
foo && bar
```

Bash interprets that as two separate simple commands — `foo` and `bar` — joined by the control operator `&&`.

But when you write something like this:

```
cmd='foo && bar'
$cmd
```

you only have *one* simple command, `$cmd`. Bash performs parameter-substitution (replacing `$cmd` with `foo && bar`) and word-splitting (replacing `foo && bar` with `foo` `&&` `bar`), but it doesn't search for any special characters like `&&` or `>` or `|` or `'`.

---

To fix this, you'll need to use a different approach. In your example, you're best off just eliminating the extra indirection:

```
  cd "$ansible_dir" && ansible-playbook --extra-vars env="${ENV}" "${@}"
```

but in a more complicated example, you might find it helpful to write a helper function.

Answer (score 2):

```
cmd="cd $ansible_dir && ..."
```

You can't use build a command like that in a variable, the variables are expanded only after special syntax like `&&` is interpreted.

But I can't see why you'd want to do that anyway, why not just do the `cd` command directly?

```
ansible_run() {
  ansible_dir=$(ansible_work_dir)
  cd $ansible_dir && ansible-playbook --extra-vars env="${ENV}" "$@"
}
```